# How to get single field in mongodb query?

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb

I have data like this:

```
{ id : 1, 
    book: "Flash", 
    chapters: [
        { 
      chap_no: "1", 
      sub_chapter: [
                {sub_no: 1, description: "<description>"
                },
                {sub_no: 2, description: "<description>"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to show one field like this base on book -> chapter_no -> sub_no

```
{
 sub_no: 2, description: "<description>"
}
```

in mongodb query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match`
- `$unwind`
- `$unwind`
- `$match`
- `$replaceRoot`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "chapters.sub_chapter.sub_no": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chapters"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chapters.sub_chapter"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "chapters.sub_chapter.sub_no": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$chapters.sub_chapter"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/81G71tgtpbE)

Answer (score 0):

you can make like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $and: [
        {
          "book": "Flash3"
        },
        {
          "chapters.chap_no": "2"
        },
        {
          "chapters.sub_chapter.sub_no": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chapters"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chapters.sub_chapter"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $and: [
        {
          "book": "Flash3"
        },
        {
          "chapters.chap_no": "2"
        },
        {
          "chapters.sub_chapter.sub_no": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$chapters.sub_chapter"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).